# How can I capture the first element of an expansion cycle with Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I have an array graphed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqoVc.png) with data appended over time:

How can I select the positions of the first elements in the beginning of each expansion cycle?

Comment: element is much bigger then previous one, and it is smaller then next one. So you would have to compare three adjacent elements

Comment: @furas That was another idea I also had but my first idea might work just fine

Comment: @Menotdan if you want then you could describe this idea (with example code) in your answer. OP didn't shows code and didn't use tag so I don't know if it uses numpy array or pandas DataFrame which could help to compare three elements and write shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```py
for element in array:
    if element >= limit:
        # "select" the element
```

Where array is your list and limit is how high an element can be before it is considered the beginning of an expansion cycle.